# concatenate many files into bigger file without the header

Tags: r, cmd, header, concatenation

I am trying to do this in R, but windows command line could work too.

I have let's say 10 big files, each one with a header on the first line. I would like to have a single file which includes all these files but without the header.

The fastest way I can find is to try "copy /b" command to concatenate all these files into a bigger file, and then use SED software to do a command line of finding the header patterns in that big file and deletes them.

The SED is slow and I don't want to have SED installed in any machine that will need this approach. Is there a way to use copy \b command to just paste from the second line forward into that bigger file?

I also have done technique of reading the file into memory by "fread" from data.table package and then using write.table with appending to make the bigger file. (but the write.table is super super slow and the "fwrite" command of data.table is not out on CRAN yet... it is still in development on github, and so it may not be as stable as I want it to be).

Does anybody have suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: It would help to provide a reproducible code in R. Specifically, do you want to keep the header as the first row in the final result? Is your question more about the data wrangling or about performance of read/write for large files?

Comment: If all the files have the same header, you could read all of the big files into a list in R with `MyList <- lapply()`, then use `MyData <- Reduce(function(...) rbind, MyList)` to put them all in one data frame. Or do that in one step by putting the `lapply()` in the `MyData <-` line. (This presumes that you read them in as data frames in the `lapply()` step, with the header rows as column names.)

Comment: The problem is just the speed of writing. For reading the files into memory, I am at the maximum speed possible which is hindered by the slow speed of write.table.

Comment: All the files have the same header. But what ulfeldor is saying is about how to read them all. That is not an issue (whether I read them one by one, or all at once, or bind them together), they writing back to one big file is the bottleneck. So knowing that I am not manipulating the data and would like to just concatenate them together, I think there is a way to do this process without reading them into memory and use more disk-related copying methods...

Comment: Can you do this in linux?  Do you have to use DOS?

Comment: No, it has to be windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this in R. Below is an Rscript for doing that.

```
cmdArgs<-c("peakListFile.txt") # read a list of all files that you want to concatenate
peakList<-cmdArgs[1]
peakFileDF<-read.table(peakList, header=F) # create a df for list file

tempdf<-matrix(,, ncol=10, dimnames=list(c(), c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5","V6", "V7", "V8", "V9", "V10"))) # create an empty df

for(i in peakFileDF$V1)
{
tmp<-read.delim(i, sep="\t", header=F, stringsAsFactors=F)
tempdf<-rbind(tmp, tempdf)
}
tempdf<-tempdf[rowSums(is.na(tempdf)) != ncol(tempdf),] # Removing the line with NA coming from creation of empty df above
```

Comment: This is not what I want. Your solution seems to be just about reading the list of files. Again, I have to point out, it's not about reading them (that is fast using data.table package). It's mainly about writing them; about creating a new file. I wonder about a hack that can speed up the process by not reading into memory and doing a direct file copy method of concatenation.